# Hydration Error in Next JS when accessing Zustand Persisted "token" variable to load a spinner

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, zustand

Following is _app.tsx in which I am wrapping the components/pages in a PageWrapper component which contains the logic the display loading spinner .

```
export default function App(props: MyAppProps) {

  const updateJWT = useJWTStore((state) => state.setJWT); // zustand store
  const token = useJWTStore((state) => state.JWT); //// zustand store



  const router = useRouter();
  const [openDrop, setOpenDrop] = useState<boolean>(false);



  return (
          <PageWrapper>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </PageWrapper>
  );
}
```

Following is PageWrapper.tsx which encloses all the components.The token variable is from the zustand store which contains the JWT Token.The following code attempts to show the spinner when we don't have the token and the destination page is not login page .

```
type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

const PageWrapper = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const token = useJWTStore((state) => state.JWT); //zustand store
  const router = useRouter();


  if (!token && router.route != "/login") {
    return (
      <Backdrop sx={{ color: "#fff", zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }} open={true}>
        <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
      </Backdrop>
    );
  }
  return <>{children}</>;
};

export default PageWrapper;
```

Getting hydration error once logged in on every refresh.Not able to understand how to avoid the server only rendering the loading spinner when logged in and visiting any other page.

Answer (score 0):

Zustand seems to have a solution for this, im currently using Next 13 app router. i was having similar issues so went to zustand docs, there is property called `skipHydration` which can be used to control when the hydration occurs.

what i did was , made a client component called Hydrations, and i have imported all my zustand stores and called the `rehydrate` function , [Zustand docs](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/main/docs/integrations/persisting-store-data.md#skiphydration)

**Auth slice**

```
    import { create } from 'zustand';
import { persist } from 'zustand/middleware';

interface TypeAuth {
    admin: TypeAdmin | null;
    setAdmin: (admin: TypeAdmin) => void;
}

const useAuth = create<TypeAuth>()(
    persist(
        (set) => ({
            admin: null,
            setAdmin: (admin) => {
                set({ admin });
            },
        }),
        {
            name: 'auth',
            skipHydration: true, //set this true
        }
    )
);

export default useAuth;
```

Hydration File

```
'use client';

import { useEffect } from 'react';

import { useAuth } from '@/utils/slices';

export default function Hydrations() {
    useEffect(() => {
        useAuth.persist.rehydrate();
    }, []);

    return null;
}
```

just import hydration file in _app.tsx